# call addTransactionObserver repeately once click purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I want to implement IAP with iOS, and have noticed two different ways to call addTransactionObserver .

1.Add this method once IAP was launched .this method will be called once.

2.Add this method with purchase and restore btn. I am afraid this method will be called repeately by click btn.

```
- (void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (IBAction) restore{
    //this is called when the user restores purchases, you should hook this up to a button
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Could you tell me what's the correctly way to add this method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should call addTransactionObserver only once *AND* at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Call `addTransactionObserver` in the class `init` method.
Personally I use a singleton class to manage my IAP stuff. On app launch you need to request available IAP’s anyway, so during the init of the singleton I register as the transaction observer.